# Direct SSL/TLS (no CONNECT message) MITM Proxy using c# SslStream

Tags: c#, ssl, proxy, tcpclient

I'm trying to create a local windows MITM proxy with C# to deal with a now unsupported application from a company that no longer exists.

The Proxy has to only service one HTTPS domain which is being done by creating a proxy that listens on the local address:port 127.0.0.1:443.

An entry in the host file is then created i.e. 127.0.0.1 my.single.domain.com.

When adding an entry for the domain directly into my hosts file, I do not get the normal "CONNECT" type of HTTP request, but rather on the socket I receive a direct client hello and I can see that the next step is initiate a handshake.

However, I'm unsure how to handle this using a C# `SslStream`. Most examples to be found, including in places like MSDN, are for "CONNECT" type proxys.

Do I need to create two SslStreams to handle this.

Comment: Would recommend editing your question to ask less for examples and be straight to the point with valid technical questions, otherwise people are gonna close it.

Comment: I've heavily edited your question to try and make it valid and answerable. I'm not sure that I've succeeded, but just an FYI and feel free to rollback if you disagree with the edit.

Comment: From what I understand, you just want your Proxy Server to be able to Handle the Client Hello instead of the CONNECT. Prehaps, you should give us more information about the Proxy Server, so we have an idea of how it handles requests, like does it uses MVC? etc

Comment: At the moment its just a simple console mitm proxy. Im guessing that it will need a client SSLStream and a server SSLStream. I dont need to create fake certificates for the client as I have copies of the real ones. My real issue is I know what im trying to acheive but the current examples on Google and even books I own either use the CONNECT method (not a direct ssl stream), are out of date or simply dont work. I like .net but MS keep moving the goal posts around so much its hard to get an up to date example of these type of not some common requirements.

Comment: @WilliamHumphreys When you say you have the certificates, just what kind of certs are these? They're going to be bound to a domain + IP. 127.0.0.1 is definitely not going to be the IP. Need more info.

Comment: The situation is its a piece of industrial equipment that runs from a pc. The app on the pc talks to a web service on a server also in the same building. A certificate has been created for this server and installed on the client PC. Using Burp I know that the client is simply requesting XML from the server. I need to change just one node of the returned xml for a specific request. So in theory I create an ssl/tls connection to the client then do the same to the server using TcpListners and SslStream etc I then grab the xml in the middle and change it.

Comment: I cannot alter the client nor the code on the server without a huge reverse engineering effort.

Comment: i think you are better off with making a DNS entry for the Proxy instead of using the HOST file.

Comment: The host file is a dns entry and that part works fine. Simply I can run the proxy locally on the client on 127.0.0.1:443 and set the host file to 127.0.0.1 [SERVER]. This part works fine. The reason for doing it this way is so only the clients request go through the proxy and nothing else.

Comment: When you run the Proxy on the Client with the HOST file, is the Client able to connect to the Remote Server through the proxy?

Comment: If I write some code to do that which is sort of my question really.

Comment: "I cannot alter the client nor the code on the server without a huge reverse engineering effort. " - But you said you can't alter code

Comment: There is no proxy on the client. The client connects directly to the server. I need to write a MITM proxy to intercept the conversation between the client and the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question but maybe it will give others some direction. This is not production standard code but it works.

```
public sealed class SslTcpProxy
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create a TCP/IP (IPv4) socket and listen for incoming connections.
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 443);
        tcpListener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Server listening on 127.0.0.1:433  Press enter to exit.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client to connect...");
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Application blocks while waiting for an incoming connection.
        TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        AcceptConnection(tcpClient);

        Console.ReadLine();
        tcpListener.Stop();
    }

    private static void AcceptConnection(TcpClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Using a pre-created certificate.
            String certFilePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\certificates\server-cert.pfx";

            X509Certificate2 certificate;

            try
            {
                certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFilePath, "[CER_PASSWORD]");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Could not create the certificate from file from {certFilePath}", ex);
            }

            SslStream clientSslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
            clientSslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate, false, SslProtocols.Default, false);

            // Display the properties and settings for the authenticated as server stream.
            Console.WriteLine("clientSslStream.AuthenticateAsServer");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
            DisplaySecurityLevel(clientSslStream);
            DisplaySecurityServices(clientSslStream);
            DisplayCertificateInformation(clientSslStream);
            DisplayStreamProperties(clientSslStream);

            Console.WriteLine();

            // The Ip address of the server we are trying to connect to.
            // Dont use the URI as it will resolve from the host file.
            TcpClient server = new TcpClient("[SERVER_IP]", 443);
            SslStream serverSslStream = new SslStream(server.GetStream(), false, SslValidationCallback, null);
            serverSslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("[SERVER_NAME]");

            // Display the properties and settings for the authenticated as server stream.
            Console.WriteLine("serverSslStream.AuthenticateAsClient");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
            DisplaySecurityLevel(serverSslStream);
            DisplaySecurityServices(serverSslStream);
            DisplayCertificateInformation(serverSslStream);
            DisplayStreamProperties(serverSslStream);

            new Task(() => ReadFromClient(client, clientSslStream, serverSslStream)).Start();
            new Task(() => ReadFromServer(serverSslStream, clientSslStream)).Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

    }

    private static Boolean SslValidationCallback(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslpolicyerrors)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private static void ReadFromServer(Stream serverStream, Stream clientStream)
    {
        Byte[] message = new Byte[4096];

        Int32 serverBytes;

        try
        {
            while ((serverBytes = serverStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length)) > 0)
            {
                clientStream.Write(message, 0, serverBytes);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Whatever
        }
    }

    private static void ReadFromClient(TcpClient client, Stream clientStream, Stream serverStream)
    {
        Byte[] message = new Byte[4096];

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("client");

        if (!fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            fileInfo.Create().Dispose();
        }

        using (FileStream stream = fileInfo.OpenWrite())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Int32 clientBytes;

                try
                {
                    clientBytes = clientStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
                }
                catch
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (clientBytes == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                serverStream.Write(message, 0, clientBytes);
                stream.Write(message, 0, clientBytes);
            }

            client.Close();
        }
    }

    static void DisplaySecurityLevel(SslStream stream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cipher: {0} strength {1}", stream.CipherAlgorithm, stream.CipherStrength);
        Console.WriteLine("Hash: {0} strength {1}", stream.HashAlgorithm, stream.HashStrength);
        Console.WriteLine("Key exchange: {0} strength {1}", stream.KeyExchangeAlgorithm, stream.KeyExchangeStrength);
        Console.WriteLine("Protocol: {0}", stream.SslProtocol);
    }

    static void DisplaySecurityServices(SslStream stream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Is authenticated: {0} as server? {1}", stream.IsAuthenticated, stream.IsServer);
        Console.WriteLine("IsSigned: {0}", stream.IsSigned);
        Console.WriteLine("Is Encrypted: {0}", stream.IsEncrypted);
    }

    static void DisplayStreamProperties(SslStream stream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Can read: {stream.CanRead}, write {stream.CanWrite}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Can timeout: {stream.CanTimeout}");
    }

    static void DisplayCertificateInformation(SslStream stream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Certificate revocation list checked: {stream.CheckCertRevocationStatus}");

        X509Certificate localCertificate = stream.LocalCertificate;

        if (stream.LocalCertificate != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Local cert was issued to {0} and is valid from {1} until {2}.",
                localCertificate.Subject,
                localCertificate.GetEffectiveDateString(),
                localCertificate.GetExpirationDateString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Local certificate is null.");
        }

        // Display the properties of the client's certificate.
        X509Certificate remoteCertificate = stream.RemoteCertificate;

        if (stream.RemoteCertificate != null)
        {
            if (remoteCertificate != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Remote cert was issued to {remoteCertificate.Subject} and is valid from {remoteCertificate.GetEffectiveDateString()} until {remoteCertificate.GetExpirationDateString()}.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Remote certificate is null.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably remove the complaining from your answer and add some actual comments. Posting a block of code doesn't do much. Also, I've written multiple local MITM programs and I had your question in mind. I spent 2 years writing the last local MITM software I wrote, you gave people 5 hours before you complained. I'm not telling you this to start a fight, I'm telling you because you've made someone who is, if I dare say so myself, an expert in what you're asking completely uninterested in answering. That's something to consider.

Comment: It does not work... BufferSize is not defined in the scope.

Comment: This is a snippet of a much larger application a long time ago. It isn't there to be taken verbatim but as a guide. And it works fine in that context. As it stands just replace BufferSize with message.Length.